# Error R10 (Boot timeout) Heroku with python script

Tags: python, heroku

I am running a python script that periodically scrapes a website then goes to sleep for 40 minutes.

The thing is, my script never 'finishes' running, it is essentially an infinite while loop that sleeps for 40 minutes, scrapes, then goes back to sleep:

```
x = 0 
while x == 0:
    scrape_website()
    time.sleep(2400)
```

So, I am assuming because my file never 'finishes' running I am getting this error in my Heroku logs:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not the problem. The problem is, as the error describes, a `web` process has to bind to a port so that it can receive requests and actually serve a website. If you're not serving a website, you need to use a different kind of process.

Comment: I see. Would you know what the procfile for a simple python script should be? (I simply want to run some_script.py)